# How to decrease font size or spacing of my text with in the word document that is generated using openxml in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I am successfully generating a word document using openxml. My Word document contains a pie chart and text. now the issue is the last line within the Legends is hiding due to less height and I have only 3 options that i am unable to do.

- Decrease the font size or
- Decrease the line spacing between my text
- Increase legends height ( Not allowed to increase chart area height due to some obstacles)

I have tried the following scenerios

- Linespacing properties,
- font size
- intentions
- justifications
- textproperties
- chart area
- paragraph properties.

Here's the code:

```
public void CreateChart(List<ChartSubArea> chartList, string variable, string id)
    {

    dc.Legend legend2 = new dc.Legend();
    dc.LegendPosition legendPosition2 = new dc.LegendPosition() 
         { val = dc.LegendPositionValues.Right };
    dc.Overlay overlay3 = new dc.Overlay() { Val = false };
    legend2.Append(legendPosition2);
    legend2.Append(overlay3);

    dc.TextProperties textPros = new TextProperties();
    textPros.Append(new d.BodyProperties());
    textPros.Append(new d.ListStyle());

    d.Paragraph paragraph = new d.Paragraph();
    d.ParagraphProperties paraPros = new d.ParagraphProperties();
    d.DefaultParagraphProperties defaultParaPros = new d.DefaultParagraphProperties();
    defaultParaPros.Append(new d.LatinFont() { Typeface = "Arial", PitchFamily = 34, CharacterSet = 0 });
    defaultParaPros.Append(new d.ComplexScriptFont() { Typeface = "Arial", PitchFamily = 34, CharacterSet = 0 });
    paraPros.Append(defaultParaPros);
    paragraph.Append(paraPros);
    paragraph.Append(new d.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-Us" });

    textPros.Append(paragraph);

 }
```

Comment: A suggestion: Download the "OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool" from the Microsoft site.  Using your code above, create the document you want.  Open it in Word.  Make a very small change (unrelated to this problem) and save the document.  Now fix the issue (within Word), making he document appear the way you want.  Save the fixed document under another name.  Use the Productivity tool to diff the two documents and see where you need to add your fixes.  That tool makes OpenXML SDK development *way* easier

Comment: Great! This is something that I have not tried. Thank you so much I shall give it a try